# abrir dos links en el controlador?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo un controlador que guarda los datos cuando hago cambios y me redirecciona a la pagina principal cuando hago un update.

```
return redirect()->route('payments.update', $payments->loan_id);
```

todo bien, la cosa que quiero imprimir un pdf

```
return redirect()->route('pdf.report', array('id' => $payments->id,'tipo' => 1));
```

tambien me abre la pagina y veo mi pdf todo bien. sin problemas.

pero mi consulta es:

¿cómo puedo hacer que vaya a mi página "payments.update", pero que antes me abra una nueva ventana con el link del "pdf.report"?

PaymentController.php

```
    public function index($id)
{
    $payments = Loan::searchid($id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(10);
    return view('payments.index', ['opcion' => 1])->with('payments', $payments);

}

public function pay($id)
{
    $payments = Payment::searchid($id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(10);
    return view('payments.index', ['opcion' => 2])->with('payments', $payments);

}
public function update(PaymentRequest $request, $id)
    {
    $payments->save();
    $loans->save();
    // aqui me guarda los cambios, omiti lo demas por que era muy extenso.
    return redirect()->route('payments.update', $payments->loan_id);
    // return redirect()->route('pdf.report', array('id' => $payments->id,'tipo' => 1));
}
```

---

Routes:

```
Route::get('/payments/{id}', ['uses'=>'PaymentsController@index','as'=>'payments.index']);
Route::get('/payments/{id}/pay', ['uses'=>'PaymentsController@pay','as'=>'payments.pay']);
Route::get('/payments/{id}/paid', ['uses'=>'PaymentsController@paid','as'=>'payments.paid']);
Route::put('/payments/{id}/pay', ['uses'=>'PaymentsController@update','as'=>'payments.update']);

//PDFs
Route::get('reportes', 'PdfController@index');
Route::get('crear-reporte-clientes/{tipo}', 'PdfController@crear_reporte_clientes');
Route::get('payments/{id}/paid/report/{tipo}',['uses'=>'PdfController@paid_report','as'=>'pdf.report']);
```

---

PdfController.php

```
  public function index()
  {
    return view("pdf.listado_reportes");
  }


  public function crearPDF($loans,$vistaurl,$tipo)
{
    $data = $loans;
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $view =  \View::make($vistaurl, compact('data', 'date'))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);

    if($tipo==1){return $pdf->stream('reporte');}
    if($tipo==2){return $pdf->download('reporte.pdf'); }
}

public function crear_reporte_pago($loans,$vistaurl,$tipo)
{
    $data = $loans;
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.report_paid',['nombre'=> $loans->loan->client->nombre,'id' => $loans->id,'pay_id' => $loans->loan_id, 'pago' => $loans->pago, 'pago_abono' => $loans->pago_abono, 'motivo' => $loans->motivo,'fecha_pago' => $loans->fecha_pago, 'estado' => $loans->estado, 'fecha_pagado' => $loans->updated_at]);
    if($tipo==1){return $pdf->stream('reporte');}
    if($tipo==2){return $pdf->download('reporte.pdf'); }
}


public function crear_reporte_clientes($tipo){

 $vistaurl="pdf.reporte_de_clientes";
 $loans=loan::all();
 return $this->crearPDF($loans, $vistaurl,$tipo);
}

public function paid_report($id,$tipo){

 $vistaurl="pdf.report_paid";
 $loans=Payment::find($id);

 return $this->crear_reporte_pago($loans, $vistaurl,$tipo);
}
```

Comment: Realmente el problema aquí es más de la lógica de tu aplicación, según como abordes el problema, te podría dar una idea si muestras el código de ambos controladores/métodos.

Comment: bueno algo asi. no se si se entienda ahora. la cosa es cuando llamo a la funcion Update. me guarda todo sin problemas y me redirecciona. cosa que me sirve. pero aparate quisiera abrir una nueva pestaña o un popup con el otro link que es el que me abre un pdf. pero no se como hacerlo. ya que no puedo pegar dos redirect() me abre solo el primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que no puedes generar dos respuestas HTTP al tiempo, se me ocurre abrir en una nueva ventana el pdf generado, desde la vista de la página principal, según lo describes.

En la vista correspondiente puedes incluir algo así:

```
<script>window.open({{ route('pdf.report', ['id' => $payments->id,'tipo' => 1]) }});</script>
```

Debes tener en cuenta además:

- Pasar la variable `$payments->id` a la vista
- Es posible que los bloqueadores de publicidad no colaboren mucho al momento de abrir la nueva ventana con el pdf.

Comment: ok, me imaginaba que no se podian abrir dos ventanas desde el controlador. entonces tendre que manejarlo por la vista. ocupare tu ejemplo gracias otra vez. estoy aprendiendo mucho de tus ayudas. saludos.